# Fixed Effects Variation

Tags: econometrics

Suppose I wish to run the following gravity regression: 
$$
Y_{ijt}=\boldsymbol{X_{ijt}'\beta+}ij+i_{t}+j_{t}+\epsilon_{ijt}
$$
where the LHS is bilateral trade between $i$ and $j$ in year $t,$
the first part of the RHS denotes control variables, specific to $i$ and $j$. The term $ij$
is the pair fixed effects term, which is a fixed effect for a particular
term. The third term is the importer-time fixed effect, and the fourth
term is the exporter fixed effect. Importantly, within each year,
I have bilatereal information between various possible combinations
of importers and exporters. My questions are as follows: 1) Are the
coefficients on $ij$, $i_{t}$ and $j_{t}$ identified? My first
inkling is yes. That is because, assuming a balanced panel, the total
number of observations are:
$$
T\times I\times J
$$
 whereas the number of coefficients to be identified as:
$$
IJ+IT+JT
$$
 which is less than $TIJ$ if:
$$
IJ\left(1-\frac{1}{T}\right)>I+J
$$
 which should generally be the case.

2) On what basis is $\beta$ identified? What variation is being used?
The $ij$ pair fixed effects would imply this is being identified
from within country pair- over time variation in $\boldsymbol{X.}$
What role does $i_{t}$ and $j_{t}$ play?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't enough to have a large number of observations. You need multiple observations of each $i$ and $j$ for multiple time periods and doing trade with multiple countries. If, for example, if countries $k$ and $l$ only trade with each other, it wouldn't be possible to distinguish between $k$, $l$, and $lk$. In additions, you need multiple observations because you want to identify a time subscript on $i$ and $j$. If you have many countries, many periods, and many trade relationships, and the data are not sparse then this may not matter much.

You may find this paper of use:
Gravity or dummies? the limits of identification in gravity estimations ([Hornok 2011](http://www.freit.org/WorkingPapers/Papers/TradePolicyGeneral/FREIT426.pdf))

> This paper argues that identification of trade policy effects with a
>   gravity equation that includes country-time dummies to control for the
>   theoretical Multilateral Trade Resistances (MTR) is severely limited.
>   In most cases heterogeneous policy effects, i.e. more than one policy
>   dummies, cannot be identified separately, because the policy dummies
>   and the country-time dummies are perfectly collinear. Although a
>   single policy dummy can b e identified, the estimate may not b e
>   meaningful, because country-time dummies absorb to o much of the
>   useful variation of the data. Standard estimation techniques often do
>   not reveal these problems. The pap er demonstrates these arguments by
>   taking four typical research questions on the effect of a trade
>   policy, checking the
>   identifiability of the corresponding policy effect and deriving the
>   estimates. Empirical exercise on estimating the trade effects of EU
>   enlargement complements the analytical findings.

And Estimating the gravity model without gravity using panel data
([Westerlund and  Wilhelmsson 2009](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00036840802599784))

> "...$\alpha_{ij}$ which is unidentified in the fixed effects
>   formulation of the model. In order to identify $\alpha_{ij}$, a random
>   effects assumption is needed. But such assumptions are generally not
>   satisfied in practice..."

@ChinG, here is the basic gravity idea:
Newton's law of universal gravitation tells us that the force of gravity is
$$F = \frac{G M_1 M_2}{R^{2}_{1,2}}$$
which implies
$$f = g + m_1 + m_2 - 2 \cdot r_{1,2} $$
(where lowercase letters are the logs of upper case ones). In the trade equation, the force of gravity is replaced with the volume of trade. Usually, $M_1$ represents the economic size of economy one (say measured by $GDP_1$ and in your regression analogous to $I_t$), $M_2$ represents the economic size of economy two ($GDP_2$ and analogous to $J_t$), and $r_{1,2}$ is the geographic or effective economic distance between the two countries ($\alpha_{i,j}$). GDP isn't exactly the right measure because countries differ in fraction of the economy devoted to trad-able output. Think of it as analogous to the importance of that country in global trade (in an absolute and not relative sense).

Comment: Hi @Bkay, thanks a lot for your response. In your explanation, is it possible to indicate what the coefficients on j,i and ij are intuitively measuring?

Comment: Let me know if this update is what you needed.

Comment: Sorry @BKay, I think I was not clear in my question. My question is generalizable to any question with multiple (twoway or threeway fixed effects). My question more specifically is: I am searching for the intuition behind what the fixed effects terms are measuring, not in a gravity setting but more generally- and moreover, how they are identified in the present context.  So for instance, j is perhaps identified by calculating the average trade flows where j is an exporter. I'm not able to properly put my finger on the precise source of variation. How is i and j separately identified from ij?